# ASP.NET : how to get Value of QueryString in thread method?

Tags: asp.net

I got an error when trying to get the value of `Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["PLCID"].ToString())` in the thread method and i tried to use parameterizedthread but faild

here my code snippet

```
protected void btnReqConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Int32 val = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["PLCID"].ToString());
    id = Guid.NewGuid();

    ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(longRunningProcess);
    Thread th = new Thread(ts);
    th.Start();

    Response.Redirect("Status.aspx?ID="+id.ToString());
}
protected void longRunningProcess()
{
    String _MachineName = String.Empty;
    _MachineIP = String.Empty;
    DBLayer.getMachineByPLCID(Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["PLCID"].ToString()), out _MachineName, out _MachineIP);

    if (DBLayer.insertRequest(User.Identity.Name, DBLayer.getMachineID(_MachineName), Convert.ToDateTime(lblReqFromVal.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(lblReqToVal.Text)))
    {
        _PLCName = DBLayer._getPlCByID(Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["PLCID"].ToString()));

        //stop mail now
        LogicLayer.AddNewListItem("Confirmation Mail", "You can initiate your session directly from this link : " + string.Format(@"http://IP/RRRProject/DirectSessionPage.aspx?Machine={0}", _MachineIP), (User.Identity.Name).Substring(5) + "@invensys.com");
        lblConfirmationMessage.Visible = true;
        lblConfirmationMessage.ForeColor = Color.Green;

        Thread.Sleep(9000);
        SimpleProcessCollections.Add(id, "Some result.");
    }
}
```

any idea??

Comment: Mind posting some details of this error that you speak of? Also multi-threading with asp.net doesn't work like it does with traditional applications. You cannot have a side-thread updating the controls after the main thread has already done `Request.Response()`. (maybe you want to look into AJAX?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the new Thread is not tied to the same `HttpContext` of the first one; a `Request.QueryString` call is a call to `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString` so ts won't see the parameters of your webapplications.

Anyway, you can pass the QueryString to the Thread and use it. Look at the code sample.

```
protected void btnReqConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 ...
   ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(longRunningProcess(Request.QueryString));
 ...
}

protected void longRunningProcess(NameValueCollection queryString)
{
 ...

    _PLCName = DBLayer._getPlCByID(Int32.Parse(queryString["PLCID"].ToString()));
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't just pass the querystring or an object of the values you'll need from it into your function?